# React HOC with WrappedComponent in Hook version Always re init the state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a HOC, currently i wanna revamp it to Hook version, however i found that it always render

let see the example:

```
const f = ()=> { console.log("init"); return "";}
const hoc = ({someProp = ""}) => WrappedComponent => {
   const HOC = ({...props}) => {
       const [selected, setSelected] = useState(f());
       return <WrappedComponent {...props} setSelected={setSelected}/>
   }
   return HOC;
}
```

f() will always call when setSelected trigger from WrappedComponent

let see the other example:

```
const f = ()=> { console.log("init"); return "";}
const hoc = ({someProp = ""}) => WrappedComponent => {
   class HOC extends Component {
         constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {selected: f()}
            this.setSelected = this.setSelected.bind(this);
         }
         setSelected(value) {
            this.setState({selected:value})
        }
        render() {
           return <WrappedComponent {...props} setSelected={this.setSelected}/>

        }
  }

  return HOC;
}
```

f() will only call once

How do i solve this case if i must use Hoc Format, but just wanna hoc itself become a functional component?

or i just change

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(f());
```

to

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(() => f());
```

Comment: Maybe this FAQ on ReactJS official site will help you: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-create-expensive-objects-lazily

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing the `useState`.

**Every time the HOC render, `f()` will be called.**

Let me verbose here, maybe the following code would make you see more clearly

```js
const hoc = ({someProp = ""}) => WrappedComponent => {
   const HOC = ({...props}) => {
       const state = f(); // Sure, this line would be executed every time.
       const [selected, setSelected] = useState(state);
       ...
   }
  ...
}
```

I guess that you want to execute `f()` to get init state when initializing Component and then let the Component handle the state itself, although it is not recommended.

For this scenario, I would prefer one of the following approaches:

1. Pass the result of `f()` from parent to HOC component

   > This is the simplest way that create HOC and generate init state at same time
2. use `useEffect` if the first time rendering with blank state is fine.

   > You can think `useEffect` as old `didMount` lifecycle API.

Comment: actually i just want f() run once, this already solve = const [selected, setSelected] = useState(f());

to

const [selected, setSelected] = useState(() => f());

Comment: I didn't know `useState` can accept function as parameter. Or you can use `useState(f)`, less wordy

Answer (score 0):

the answer is change

const [selected, setSelected] = useState(f());

to

const [selected, setSelected] = useState(() => f());

and f() will only call once no matter how many time it render, except unmount

Comment: You could also write `useState(f);`